# Trying to remove \n from my list but keeps coming up with an error

Tags: python, list

So I have finally succeeded in making it so that I can read from my text file and add it to a list. But now I have the slight problem of each value looks like this 6\n. How do I fix this do I need to restructure my code.
Below is the code.

The error:

```
Number guessing game with highscores.py", line 42, in <module>
    highscoreS = [highscores.replace("\n", "") for highscores in highscoreS]
NameError: name 'highscoreS' is not defined
```

Even though I have clearly defined it

```
from random import randint
a = True
n = randint(1,10)
guesses = 0

#If scores ever need to be reset just run function
def overwritefile():
    f = open("Numbergame.txt", "w")
    f.close()

#overwritefile()
#Guessing Game Code
while a == True:
    guess = int(input("What is your guess? \nEnter a number!"))
    if guess > n:
        print("Guess is too high! \nTry Again!")
        guesses += 1
    elif guess < n:
        print("Guess is too low! \nTry Again!")
        guesses += 1
    else:
        guesses += 1
        a = False

print("You guessed the number! \nIt was " + str(n) + "\nIt took you: " + str(guesses) + " guesses")

#Adding Score to the file
f = open("Numbergame.txt", "a")
f.write(str(guesses) + '\n')
f.close()


highscores = []
#Compare values and figure out if it is a new highscore
#Maybe I will use the TRY thing got taught recently might help iron out some errors
#f = open("Numbergame.txt").readlines()
with open('Numbergame.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for highscore in f:
        highscores.append(highscore)
        highscoreS = [highscores.replace('\n', '') for highscores in highscoreS]
```

Comment: The code producing your error is not the same code you shared. Regardless, if your code actually has `highscoreS = [highscores.replace("\n", "") for highscores in highscoreS]`, that means that `highscoreS` and `highscores` are treated as separate variables since Python is case sensitive. I assume you meant to distinguish the two, even though naming them almost the same thing isn't good practice. Meaning that your definition of `highscoreS` relies on it already existing and having a value. So, at that point, `highscoreS` has not yet been defined. Why do you think it is defined at that point?

Comment: The failing line is not in the code you've posted. There seems to be a lower case / upper case `S` thing going on here. Is that intentional?

Comment: Better would be `highscores.append(highscore.strip())`.

Comment: @tdelaney it was intentional as I was trying something I saw on some code I was copying, but it appeared it didn't work for me.

Comment: I have edit in the fix to the code to show where the error was

Comment: @TimRoberts the strip didn't work as it gave the error 'str object has no attribute append'. Maybe I could try defining it as something other than a string but I have no clue how to fix the problem I still have.

Comment: 'highscores' was the list you're compiling.  It shouldn't be a string.  `highscore` was the string you read from file `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Even though I have clearly defined it"*

You need to have defined it *before* it's used. As of now, `highscoreS` is used in the same line that it is defined. The correct way would be to read all values into a list first, and *then* use the list you defined.

```
highscores = []
with open('Numbergame.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        highscores.append(line)

# Notice this is OUTSIDE the loop
highscoreS = [hs.replace('\n', '') for hs in highscores]
```

To overwrite the original `highscores`, you can do

```
highscores = [hs.replace('\n', '') for hs in highscores]
```

However, this is unnecessarily convoluted. Instead of doing it this way, I suggest you simply `strip()` the whitespace *when you read* the score.

```
highscores = []
with open('Numbergame.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        highscores.append(line.strip()) # Or line.replace('\n', '')
```

You also probably want to convert the values to integers, in which case it makes sense to also do that in the loop when you read the lines from the file.

```
highscores = []
with open('Numbergame.txt', 'rt') as f:
    for line in f:
        highscores.append(int(line)) # No need to strip because `int()` automatically takes care of that
```

You can condense this down even more into a pythonic list comprehension, as @tdelaney mentioned:

```
with open('Numbergame.txt', 'rt') as f:
    highscores = [int(line) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man this was extremely helpful as I'm still new to coding an didn't fully understand what I did wrong.

Comment: Good answer, it could even condense down to opening the file and then `highscores = [int(line) for line in f]` No need to predefine the list or the for loop with append.

Comment: Thats what I did in the end, I was genuinely stuck on this problem for way to long.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi at the moment due to the amount of reputation I have I cannot upvote as I need 15 and I have one. All I can do is say thanks for the help.

Comment: @tdelaney absolutely! I originally thought condensing the loop to a comprehension should be left that as an exercise for OP, but maybe it makes sense to add it to my answer for completeness.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Yeah I realized that after I posted it thats why I deleted it. I though I would have to close it like on other forums.